# G Suite + Count amount of files by type in Domain Google Drive

Tags: google-workspace, google-reporting-api

I'm looking for an old report that is actually not appearing anymore in Google Admin Console. In this report i mentioned, i was able to see the % of files (docs, sheets, presentations, etc..) of the total amount of drive files in my domain.

Example:
Google Drive has 1000 files (500 Mb) (in the entired domain)
500 Google spreadsheet 50%, 250 Mb
150 Google Docs 15%, 75 Mb

I tried to find this information in [Admin Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) without success.

Comment: Have you check if the following references could help you find out? [Account activity reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4580176?hl=en), [Data retention and lag times](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566), [G Suite apps activity reports](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579578?hl=en)

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 G Suite Apps Activity is usefull for activity, but i want stats of totals drive files and wich types of files ....